# Norm map of ideles and injectivity of corresponding map on Galois groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory

I'm referring to another question of mine, since it made me think about this:

[Kronecker-Weber false for non-trivial number fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85775/kronecker-weber-false-for-number-fields-distinct-from-mathbbq)

What I'm essentially asking for is given two number fields $L/K$ and the norm map $N_{L/K}:C_L\to C_K$ between the idele class groups, then how will noninjectivity transfer to the profinite completion? In general given a map $f:G\to G'$ between some groups will that always induce a map between the profinite completions (e.g. is it functorial) and how/when will injectivity/surjectivity transfer?

It seems like my books on number theory leave out these parts of the theory of profinite groups.

Comment: Regarding your last question, any group homomorphism $f:H\to G$ induces a map on profinite completions $\hat{f}:\widehat{H}\to\widehat{G}$ by general nonsense. If $f$ is surjective then $\hat{f}$ is too, obviously. It may be the case that $f$ is injective but $\hat{f}$ is not, even if $H$ and $G$ are residually finite.

Comment: What about $f$ noninjective but $\hat{f}$ injective? That's really what's needed for the number theoretic problem.

Comment: @asdf: there are easy examples with $f$ non-injective but $\hat{f}$ injective: Let $f: Q \to Z$ be the zero map. Then $\hat{f}: \hat{Q} \to \hat{Z}$ is injective since $\hat{Q} = 0$. 

Comment: @SGP: Is a reason for why this is not injective for the maps between idele class groups without invoking the result that I'm trying to show?

Comment: @SGP: The question makes more sense when both $H$ and $G$ are residually finite, so that these groups embed in their profinite completions. 

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [Grothendieck problem](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/bridson/papers/fritz/FritzFinal.pdf) solved by Bridson and Grunewald. Also this paper may be relevant to what you want:
 Coulbois, Thierry; Sapir, Mark; Weil, Pascal A note on the continuous extensions of injective morphisms between free groups to relatively free profinite groups. Publ. Mat. 47 (2003), no. 2, 477–487.