# Non-cyclotomic abelian extensions

Tags: class-field-theory, nt.number-theory

Suppose $L|\mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian extension of number fields. Then, all the roots of unity are certainly contained in the maximal abelian extension $L^{ab}$ of $L$. Why is it obvious that if $L \ne \mathbb{Q}$ then $L^{ab} \ne \mathbb{Q}^{ab}$.

Comment: What prevents $L$ from having an abelian extension which is not even galoisian over $\mathbf{Q}$, let alone abelian over $\mathbf{Q}$ ?  Consider for example quadratic extensions of quadratic extensions.

Comment: Thanks Chandan! I guess the argument you had in mind is the same as the one below.

Comment: Related post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85775/kronecker-weber-false-for-number-fields-distinct-from-mathbbq

Comment: Thanks for the link Keith. I think the comments of Lavender Honey and SGP there give a reasonably complete answer. Let P a prime of $\mathbb{Q}$ split in $L$, and consider a quadratic extension $K$ of $L$ ramified at one prime $\mathcal{P}$ over $P$ but not at another $\mathcal{P}'|P$. Suppose $K \subset L*\mathbb{Q}(\mu_\infty)$, then $K$ is obtained by adjoining some element $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\mu_\infty)$ to $L$. However, looking locally at primes of $L(\alpha)$ over $P$ we see that all the local extensions are the same (infact, they are all $Q_p(\alpha)$)$. But, this is diff. from K|L 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>Pick some $\gamma_1\in L\setminus\mathbb Q$ which is not a square.</strike>  Pick some $\gamma\in L^\times/(L^\times)^2$ which is not fixed by $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)$ and fix a lift $\gamma_1\in L$.  Let $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n$ be the orbit of $\gamma_1$ under $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)$.  Then it is an easy exercise in Galois theory to show that:

1. $L(\sqrt{\gamma_1},\ldots,\sqrt{\gamma_n})/L$ is Galois with abelian Galois group $\subseteq(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$.
2. $L(\sqrt{\gamma_1},\ldots,\sqrt{\gamma_n})/\mathbb Q$ is Galois with nonabelian Galois group $\subseteq\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)\ltimes(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$.

Comment: In #2 is it really obvious that the extension is non-abelian?

Comment: Yes. It is easy to compute the action by conjugation of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)$ on $(\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z)^n$, and it is nontrivial.

Comment: I think this argument has a little hole. Consider an A4-extension K/Q of the rationals, let L be its cyclic cubic subfield, and F/L a quadratic extensions of F/L. If the square root of  c in L generates F, then your argument predicts that c has an orbit of length 2 under the action of the cyclic Galois group of order 3. For getting rid of this problem you probably have to consider orbits in L^* modulo squares.

Comment: @Franz Lemmermeyer: I don't understand your objection.  Do you mean that the Galois closure of $L(\sqrt c)$ is $K$, which has degree four over $L$?  I think this is ok, since I said that the Galois group of $L(\sqrt{\gamma_1},\ldots,\sqrt{\gamma_n})$ is *contained* in $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$, (it may be a proper subgroup).  What I need is only that it is a *nontrivial* subgroup (hence I need that $\gamma$ is not a square) because this is what makes (2) true.

Comment: @Franz Lemmermeyer: OK, I fixed a problem, but I don't think it's exactly what you said.  The edit now ensures that $\operatorname{Gal}(L(\sqrt{\gamma_1},\ldots,\sqrt{\gamma_n})/\mathbb Q)$ is nonabelian.

Comment: @unknown: you're right, I did not see the inclusion signs. There is, by the way, a beautiful article by Waterhouse (The normal closures of certain Kummer extensions, Can. Math. Bull. 37, No.1, 133-139 (1994)) dealing with problems like this one.